# Can't limit boundaries of a plotted shapefile properly

Tags: r, plot, raster, shapefile, r-sp

I can't really set the boundaries of my plotted shapefile. I'm plotting the shapefile first to get nice x- and y- labels in degrees first, plotting the data afterwards. In the end, I'm plotting my shapefile over the data again. `ylim` is changeable, but `xlim` seems to be solely dependend on `ylim` changes, because I cant vary `xlim` itself. It only varies, when I change `ylim` without changing `xlim`, like as it is an aspect ratio issue.

I want to limit the x-axis between 8.5 and 11.5 degrees.

A link to the shapefile and raster in question: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/l42mty01mwtm8qc/AADqjNbGkmNwx3o9aFceGrkya?dl=0

My code:

```
library(rgeos)
library(rgdal)
library(raster)

Sys.setlocale(category = "LC_ALL", locale = "C") # In the case German Umlauts are a problem while reading the shapefile
map <- readOGR("C:\\Path\\NATRAUM_MR_utm32.shp")

# Exclude unnecessary regions
map <- subset(map, NATREGNR != 3) 
map <- subset(map, NATREGNR != 4)
map <- subset(map, NATREGNR != 9)
map_wgs84 <- spTransform(map, crs(raster.percent.change.rcp85.1971_2005.2071_2100))

# Pixelplot
par(mar = c(3, 3, 2, 1))  # For saving pictures through a device like pdf

m <- plot(map_wgs84, axes=TRUE, xlim = c(8.5, 11.5), ylim=c(51.35, 53.15), cex = .5,
      bty = "n")

# Colortable for legend
colTab <- c("#0033CC", "#3366FF", "#6699FF","#99FFFF", "#FFCC99","#FF9933", "#FF4D00","#660000")

N <- length(colTab)
breaks <- seq(-2, 2,  length.out= N+1 )

plot(raster.percent.change.rcp85.1971_2005.2071_2100, col = colTab, breaks = breaks,
       axis.args = list(cex.axis = 1, at = breaks, labels = breaks, mgp = c(1, 0, 0), tck = 0.1),
       legend.args = list(text='Change [%]', side=4, font=2, line=1.75, cex=0.7),
        add = TRUE
```

)

```
plot(map_wgs84, add = TRUE)  # Plotting shapefile over data
```

[image: Change]

Comment: Maybe try setting `xaxs` and `yaxs` to "i" like at: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-geo/2011-November/013548.html

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Unfortunately, it doesn't work in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You need to resize your plotting window. You can use `par(fin=c(x,y))`, or `png()` to set a  ratio that works, and fix that in code.

This is because for maps, the correct aspect (ratio of vertical and horizontal extent) is enforced. For planar data the aspect is 1. For angular data (longitude/latitude) it varies by latitude.

With some data.

```
library(raster)
p <- shapefile(system.file("external/lux.shp", package="raster"))
```

Compare:

```
par(fin=c(6,6))
plot(p, axes=T, xlim=c(6,6.2), ylim=c(49.6, 49.8))

par(fin=c(4, 6))
plot(p, axes=T, xlim=c(6,6.2), ylim=c(49.6, 49.8))
```